# Removing a row in a data frame conditional on the row previous

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

```
  State Year APPT   mood ranney_4yrs folded_ranney_4yrs time censor
Arizona 1970    3 47.778   0.3299708          0.8299708   30      0
Arizona 1971    3 51.948   0.3265375          0.8265375   31      0
Arizona 1972    3 48.429   0.3246062          0.8246062   32      0
Arizona 1973    3 42.909   0.3226750          0.8226750   33      0
Arizona 1974    1 40.548   0.3683167          0.8683167   34      1
Arizona 1975    1 39.517   0.4139583          0.9139583   35      1
Arizona 1976    1 38.659   0.4543917          0.9543917   36      1
Arizona 1977    1 36.995   0.4948250          0.9948250   37      1
```

I have this dataframe and I would like to remove all but the first instances of 1 in the censor column.  What code can I write that will keep the first instance and remove all subsequent instances of a 1 in the censor column?

Comment: `dat[cumsum(dat$censor) <= 1, ]` maybe assuming `dat` will always be ordered as you have

Comment: `df[seq(1,match(1,df$censor)),]` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will work regardless of the order of the censor column:

```
df[df$censor!=1 | ave(df$censor,df$censor,FUN=function(x) 1:length(x))==1,];
```

It works by deriving a "running count" of each distinct censor value. I've used the `ave()` function in a fairly unusual way to evaluate the expression `1:length(x)` once for each unique censor value, and the `ave()` function performs the necessary work to map each resulting "count vector" back to the order the censor values occurred in the grouping vector (i.e. the second argument to `ave()`). The contents (but not the length) of the first argument to `ave()` are completely irrelevant, because the expression `1:length(x)` depends only on the length of the group, not its contents. (But it makes sense to reuse the grouping vector for the first argument, because it's guaranteed to have the correct length, i.e. the same length as the grouping vector.) Thus, the return value of `ave()` represents a running count of each censor value, properly ordered according to the order they occurred in the censor column. The running count can then be used in the indexing operation to select only rows that occurred first, i.e. that have a running count value of 1 (at least for censor value 1; the LHS of the `|` selects in all other censor values regardless of occurrence number).

Here's a demo, where I've messed with the censor column slightly to demonstrate the order-agnosticism:

```
df <- data.frame(State=c('Arizona','Arizona','Arizona','Arizona','Arizona','Arizona','Arizona','Arizona'), Year=c(1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977), APPT=c(3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1), mood=c(47.778,51.948,48.429,42.909,40.548,39.517,38.659,36.995), ranney_4yrs=c(0.3299708,0.3265375,0.3246062,0.3226750,0.3683167,0.4139583,0.4543917,0.4948250), folded_ranney_4yrs=c(0.8299708,0.8265375,0.8246062,0.8226750,0.8683167,0.9139583,0.9543917,0.9948250), time=c(30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37), censor=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1) );
df;
##     State Year APPT   mood ranney_4yrs folded_ranney_4yrs time censor
## 1 Arizona 1970    3 47.778   0.3299708          0.8299708   30      1
## 2 Arizona 1971    3 51.948   0.3265375          0.8265375   31      0
## 3 Arizona 1972    3 48.429   0.3246062          0.8246062   32      1
## 4 Arizona 1973    3 42.909   0.3226750          0.8226750   33      0
## 5 Arizona 1974    1 40.548   0.3683167          0.8683167   34      0
## 6 Arizona 1975    1 39.517   0.4139583          0.9139583   35      1
## 7 Arizona 1976    1 38.659   0.4543917          0.9543917   36      0
## 8 Arizona 1977    1 36.995   0.4948250          0.9948250   37      1
df[df$censor!=1 | ave(df$censor,df$censor,FUN=function(x) 1:length(x))==1,];
##     State Year APPT   mood ranney_4yrs folded_ranney_4yrs time censor
## 1 Arizona 1970    3 47.778   0.3299708          0.8299708   30      1
## 2 Arizona 1971    3 51.948   0.3265375          0.8265375   31      0
## 4 Arizona 1973    3 42.909   0.3226750          0.8226750   33      0
## 5 Arizona 1974    1 40.548   0.3683167          0.8683167   34      0
## 7 Arizona 1976    1 38.659   0.4543917          0.9543917   36      0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, if the data frame is ordered by the censor column:

```
df[df[,'censor']!=1 | !duplicated(df[,'censor']),]
```